# How to purge jZebra

Tags: java, javascript, append

I am using jZebra to print labels following the tutorial here: http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialWebApplet

The problem I am having is that when I change what it prints with the print() command I see artifacts until I reboot the computer of everything else I have printed.  How do I make stuff get out of zebra after I .print()?

Code is like this:

```
var applet = document.jZebra
applet.append("blah blah")
applet.print()  //works
applet.append("something ELSE to print")
applet.print()  //prints "blah blah" and "something ELSE..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is

```
applet.clear();
```